# NIM game, random range has error when range is between 1 and 1, need quick fix (not duplicate)

Tags: python, random, numbers, range

guys. I am programming a game of NIM with the following rules:

- Start with n marbles
- take turns removing between 1 and half the marbles (currently) in the pile
- loser takes last marble/s

I randomized the initial amount of marbles. I defined a "take" value as a random integer between 1 and half the pile. The way I did this was

```
nHalf = int(nNumMarbles/2)
nCTake = int(random.randrange(1,nHalf))
```

I did it this way so that half of an odd number would round down (which it does). The problem comes at the end of the game when the User has brought the nNumMarbles down to 2 and the Computer has to nCTake a random number between 1 and nHalf--that is, between 1 and 1. Here is the how the game went when it was run (error is at the bottom):

> Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64
>   bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for
>   more information.
>
> ============ RESTART: C:/Users/Name/Documents/CISPROG1/NIM.py ============ 14
>   Welcome to the game of NIM!  There are 14 marbles in the pile.  You and the computer will take turns taking marbles from
>   the pile.  Either of you can take at most half of what remains per
>   turn.  The loser takes the last marble/s.
>
> The computer will go first.
>
> Computer's turn! Computer takes 3 marbles.
>
> 11 left!
>
> Your turn! Take between 1 and 7 marbles:
>
> 2 You took 2 marbles.
>
> 9 left!
>
> Computer's turn! Computer takes 1 marbles.
>
> 8 left!
>
> Your turn! Take between 1 and 4 marbles:
>
> 1 You took 1 marbles.
>
> 7 left!
>
> Computer's turn! Computer takes 2 marbles.
>
> 5 left!
>
> Your turn! Take between 1 and 3 marbles:
>
> 1 You took 1 marbles.
>
> 4 left!
>
> Computer's turn! Computer takes 1 marbles.
>
> 3 left!
>
> Your turn! Take between 1 and 2 marbles:
>
> 1 You took 1 marbles.
>
> 2 left!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Name/Documents/CISPROG1/NIM.py", line 27, in 
>       nCTake = int(random.randrange(1,nHalf))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\random.py", line
>   198, in randrange
>       raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)) ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1,
>   0)

...and here is my program:

```
import random
import sys
import time

nNumMarbles = int(random.randrange(10,100))
print(str(nNumMarbles))
print("Welcome to the game of NIM! \n"
      "There are " + str(nNumMarbles) + " marbles in the pile. \n"
      "You and the computer will take turns taking marbles from the pile. \n"
      "Either of you can take at most half of what remains per turn. \n"
      "The loser takes the last marble/s. \n")
#let 1 --> computer goes first, 2 --> user goes first
nFirst = random.randint(1,2)
if nFirst == 1:
    print("The computer will go first. \n")
else:
    print("You will go first. \n")

#Game progression if Computer goes first (only case I am testing)
if nFirst == 1:
    while nNumMarbles > 0:
        #Computer's turn:
        nHalf = int(nNumMarbles/2)
        nCTake = int(random.randrange(1,nHalf))
        nNumMarbles = nNumMarbles - nCTake
        print("Computer's turn! Computer takes " + str(nCTake) + " marbles. \n")
        if nNumMarbles == 0:
            print("The computer took the last marble! You win!")
            time.sleep(3)
            exit()
        else:
            pass
        print(str(nNumMarbles) + " left! \n")
        #User's turn:
        print("Your turn! Take between 1 and " +str(nHalf) + " marbles: \n")
        nUTake = int(input())
        nNumMarbles = nNumMarbles - nUTake
        print("You took " + str(nUTake) + " marbles. \n")
        if nNumMarbles == 0:
            print("You took the last marble! You lose!")
            time.sleep(3)
            exit()
        else:
            pass
        print(str(nNumMarbles) + " left! \n")
```

What went wrong? How can fix it so that when the range is between 1 and 1, the computer takes (nCTake) 1, the last marble?

Comment: bump?
What I need is better way to define nCTake (so that randrange(1,1) can be replaced with just "1". I tried to add a bunch of exceptions and it got ugly

Answer (score 1):

"The problem comes at the end of the game". Actually, the problem comes much earlier. You just don't notice it until the end. `random.randrange(a,b)` returns a random integer in the interval `[a,b)`. Note that this never includes `b`. Your code doesn't pick a random integer between 1 and half the number of remaining marbles. Instead, it picks a random number between 1 and 1 less than half the marbles.

The fix is simple: use `random.randint(a,b)`. That is a function which works the way you were expecting `random.randrange` to work.

A small point: you don't need to use `int` with regular division to compute `nHalf`. Just use `nHalf = nNumMarbles//2`. Also, there was never any point in using `int` with `random.randrange`. That function already returns an integer, even if it isn't quite the integers that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am programming a game of NIM with the following rules:

Start with n marbles
take turns removing between 1 and half the marbles (currently) in the pile
loser takes last marble/s
I randomized the initial amount of marbles. I defined a "take" value as a random integer between 1 and half the pile. The way I did this was

nHalf = int(nNumMarbles/2)
nCTake = int(random.randrange(1,nHalf))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).